# python csv: recursive string at the beginning of each row followed by writer.writerows(row)

Tags: python, csv

Currently I take some records from a database and I insert the rows into a csv file by writer.writerow() in a for loop:

```
import csv 
....
for row in output:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

but in the csv I would like to insert a first recursively string at the beginning of each row (this string is the same for all the rows). Can I do it in with the code above? Thanks

Comment: "but in the csv I would like to insert a first recursively string at the beginning of each row" can you clarify exactly what you mean? Providing examples helps a lot.

Comment: example I'd like to add 'lsb':

source rows-->10 6 4 9 0.1|66 5 5 10 2|3  5 7 1  99
output.csv -->lsb,10,6,4,9,0.1|lsb,66,5,5,10,2|lsb,3,5,7,1,99

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking how to add a constant value in the first column of each row, I believe this should work:

```
writer.writerow(["Constant Value"] + row)
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't:TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "pyodbc.Row") to list